# MySQL query using variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using pretty much all variables in my query and i am pretty sure my syntax is wrong somewhere. I have tried a lot of different ways to setup my query. Basically im trying to update a specific row with the id, and the column that is the variable $loc.

```
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `" . $tbvbr . "` SET $loc='".$addscore."' WHERE pid='".$pn."' ");
```

i also tried

```
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `" . $tbvbr . "` SET $loc='$addscore' WHERE pid='$pn' ");
```

and

```
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `" . $tbvbr . "` SET $loc=$addscore WHERE pid=$pn ");
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a call to `mysqli_error()`? It'll tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You need to use 
the appropriate method of your database library to escape your data prior to 
making the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE `" . $tbvbr . "` SET " . $loc . " = '" . $addscore . "' WHERE pid= '" . $pn . "'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works great! And i see what i need to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ".$tbvbr." SET ".$loc." = '".$addscore."' WHERE pid = ".$pn);
```